How to link resources in crossplane for openstack provider
I am experimenting with crossplane in openstack. I created a Composition that group different components, like 1 virtual machine, 1 keypair to access the machine and one volume to mount in the machine. However I couldn't find a way to link the volume attachment, that needs to be created, to the volume resource and the VM resource. The volume attachment needs the vm id and the volume id, and I couldnt find a way to obtain this ids, not with patches at least, and openstack provider dont have cross-resource reference like others providers to reference by labels for example. I would like to know if there is a standard way to link the resources in a composition for openstack provider.
Composition:

Instancev2
keyPair
Volumev3
VolumeAttachv2

https://marketplace.upbound.io/providers/crossplane-contrib/provider-openstack/v0.3.0/managed-resources?
I have tried to link the resources using patches, reading from the status of one manage resource to the composite resource and the from the composite back to the other manage resource, but this does not work.
